# Optimising a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the below SQL

```
 SELECT i.id, r.full_name, i.file_name, i.lat, i.lon,   c.name as
 category_name,     
    NOW() - i.timestamp AS age,         
    (SELECT count(*) FROM votes WHERE image_id = i.id) as total_votes 
 FROM images i INNER JOIN registrations r 
    ON i.user_id = r.id 
 INNER JOIN categories c ON i.category_id = c.id 
 WHERE i.moderated=1 
 ORDER BY total_votes DESC
 LIMIT 25
```

This averages at 10-15 seconds to run on my local environment.

Removing the ORDER BY part drops it down to 0.02ish.

Is there any way to speed up the ordering in the main statement?

UPDATE 1:
Explain for query below. 
[image: Explain for query]

UPDATE 2 : 
Rewrote the query and added some indexes in

Query

```
SELECT  votes.image_id, count(votes.id) as total_votes,
        images.file_name, images.lat, images.lon, NOW() - images.timestamp AS age,
        registrations.full_name, 
        categories.name
FROM votes
LEFT JOIN images
    ON votes.image_id = images.id
LEFT JOIN registrations
    ON images.user_id= registrations.id
LEFT JOIN categories
    ON images.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY votes.image_id 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Current Explain for the query:

[image]

Comment: start by posting the output of EXPLAIN for your query

Comment: Do you have index on all columns you join?

Comment: @Prix - Updated with explain

Comment: @DanFromGermany - not at the moment.

Comment: you need index. You are investigating `8605 * 2 * 1 * 3383` (= `58221430` !!!) rows for your query. it should have a big number first, and only a few (1-5)  rows each join afterwards.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Shall I count the votes and work backwards do you think?

Comment: No; add an `INDEX` to all columns you `JOIN`. And optimize the subquery. Look at the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Create in table `images` one column "`votes`". If have vote up for image - increment, if have vote down - decrement. You can have table `votes` parallely and check if have success inert then increment.

With this you will remove this your subselect.

After this create INDEX in `images` with `ORDER BY votes DESC` and 'moderated = 1`.

BTW, are you sure that your indexs are okey?
Also think about INNER JOIN with categories.

Comment: Added `votes` column can be maintained by two triggers on `votes` table: `.. AFTER INSERT ON votes ..` (increment value) and `.. AFTER DELETE ON votes ..` (decrement value)

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery is suboptimal :)

```
 SELECT i.id, r.full_name, i.file_name, i.lat, i.lon,   c.name as
 category_name,     
    NOW() - i.timestamp AS age,         
    COUNT(*) as total_votes 
 FROM images i INNER JOIN registrations r 
    ON i.user_id = r.id 
 LEFT JOIN votes ON i.id = votes.image_id

 INNER JOIN categories c ON i.category_id = c.id 
 WHERE i.moderated=1 
 GROUP BY i.id
 ORDER BY total_votes DESC
 LIMIT 25
```

If this doesn't help, you'll have to provide table structures and and `explain` plan of the query.

Comment: Explain added to the post... This was up at 13 seconds.

Comment: The `ALL` in column type of your explain plan means, that a full table scan is done. You have to avoid that with proper indexes. Start by adding indexes on the columns you're joining on. And you should stick to my query, yours (as you can see in column select_type) has a dependent subquery, which means that the subquery is executed for every row of your result set...very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Using TEMP TABLES for votes and registrations tables will help you to speed up the query.